# Objective-C : Is there any callback invoked when sending a message to the object that can't respond?

Tags: objective-c, ios

If I send a message to a target object, but it's the message that the target object does not know how to respond (has no definition), would there be any method invoked after this happen? In Ruby, there is a method_missing method. What's about in Objective-C, is there any equivalence?

Comment: Try using `-respondsToSelector:`, or NSUncaughtExceptionHandler.

Answer (score 2):

This throws an NSException. unrecognized selector sent to instance blah.

Answer (score 2):

As Richard J. Ross III said, you should use  -(BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector in order to see if the object responds to it. And the answer is no, there is no such thing in objective-c

Comment: I am still new to objective-c. Is it a big deal to use try-catch often?

Comment: @WarutSurapat YES. Never EVER use `@try` / `@catch`. NEVER. It uses `setjmp` and `longjmp`, which are ancient, slow, and memory-leak prone. Just don't do it, especially under ARC. Use solutions that **predict** errors, or use `NSError`'s.

Comment: Thank @Richard ;) This is a new knowledge for me. noted!

BTW, I think I found what I am looking for. It's resolveInstanceMethod method which I can override. Found it here  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html